# Is there an order state change event in Shopware 6?

Tags: php, symfony, events, shopware, subscriber

Orders in Shopware 6 have these states:

```
<?php declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Shopware\Core\Checkout\Order;

final class OrderStates
{
    public const STATE_MACHINE = 'order.state';
    public const STATE_OPEN = 'open';
    public const STATE_IN_PROGRESS = 'in_progress';
    public const STATE_COMPLETED = 'completed';
    public const STATE_CANCELLED = 'cancelled';
}
```

Is it possible to subscribe to the state changes? Is there a state change event or could these states be used as events? If yes, how to get the changed state name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find all order events in here: https://github.com/shopware/platform/blob/6.2/src/Core/Checkout/Order/OrderEvents.php

ORDER_TRANSACTION_STATE_*
or
ORDER_WRITTEN_EVENT

Should be the way to go.

After this you can get the Payload of of the EntityEvent: https://github.com/shopware/platform/blob/6.2/src/Core/Framework/DataAbstractionLayer/Event/EntityWrittenEvent.php -> getPayloads()

Answer (score 7):

The events are dispatched in the [StateMachineRegistry::transition](https://github.com/shopware/platform/blob/6.2/src/Core/System/StateMachine/StateMachineRegistry.php#L214-L240).
As you can see in the [StateMachineStateChangeEvent](https://github.com/shopware/platform/blob/6.2/src/Core/System/StateMachine/Event/StateMachineStateChangeEvent.php#L88), the event name is generated on base of the state which is changed, e.g. `state_machine.order_transaction.state_changed`

These events are even used in [Shopware itself](https://github.com/shopware/platform/blob/6.2/src/Core/Checkout/DependencyInjection/order.xml#L118-L120) to dispatch special [OrderStateMachineStateChangeEvent](https://github.com/shopware/platform/blob/6.2/src/Core/Checkout/Order/Event/OrderStateMachineStateChangeEvent.php)s. The name for these events are generated [here](https://github.com/shopware/platform/blob/6.2/src/Core/System/StateMachine/Event/StateMachineStateChangeEvent.php#L93), e.g. `state_enter.order_transaction.state.paid`